# Access 2016: Need Help Building a Query similar to Pivot in Excel?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, pivot, ms-access-2016

This is driving me bananas as I know it can't be that hard!
I have a table that has a record for every product. I'd like to create a query to that I have one line with a column for each product instead.
In Excel I'd just create a pivot table and voila, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do this in Access. The closest I can get is creating a Dsum, but then I just get the same total for each well - so I'm clearly not going about it the right way.
I just need:

LSE_ID   TECHNICALEUR(oil) TECHNICALEUR(gas)

Any help is appreciated!
[image: Source data Table]

I've tried DSUM and DLOOKUP but this is what I get:
[Expression Tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emAu6.png)
[image: Result]

Comment: Data should provided as formatted text table, not image. Code should also be text, not image.

Comment: Did you try the CROSSTAB query wizard?

Comment: For a start, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Answer (score 1):

Domain aggregate functions can cause slow performance in query. But, not needed for this requirement. Build a CROSSTAB (Access has a wizard for that) or emulate CROSSTAB with simple aggregate query using IIf().

```
SELECT Lse_Id, Sum(IIf(Product="Oil",TechnicalEUR,0)) AS SumOil, 
Sum(IIf(Product="Gas",TechnicalEUR,0)) AS SumGas 
FROM Asofdat
GROUP BY Lse_Id;
```

Side note: Your query returned same value for every record because DSum() criteria did not include Lse_Id. Consider:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Lse_Id, DSum("TechnicalEUR", "tablename", "Product='Oil' AND Lse_Id=" & Lse_Id) AS SumOil 
FROM Asofdat;
```

Avoid domain aggregate functions in queries as much as possible. Use in VBA or in textbox.